# Want to leverage a validation on a per element instead of on submission

Tags: validation, polymer, polymer-1.0

Right now, I have a simple log in with 2 paper inputs and 2 paper buttons.  username, password, cancel, submit.

Right now, i do a validation in dart when the client clicks submit, but i would like it to do it as they enter input.  It seems that using:

```
<paper-input Label="Username..."
             auto-validate validate="^[A-Za-z0-9]+$" 
             on-error-message="wrong username input"
             value="{{usr}}" id="username"></paper-input>
```

seems to never fire.  I go into the paper input, press the spacebar, and unfocus, nothing happens.  I just want to make sure a valid username is input.  Not an email, just a *contiguous string of case insensitive alphanumerics*.

I have also tried:   `auto-validate="true"`, `error-message="wrong username input"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the pattern in with `pattern` attribute instead of `validate`. For the error message, use the `error-message` attribute.

```
<paper-input Label="Username..."
         auto-validate pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+$" 
         error-message="wrong username input"
         value="{{usr}}" id="username"></paper-input>
```

Comment: I think i mistook the validate for the pattern tag?

Comment: I think so. There is a [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-input) that does what you are trying to do with a different pattern. If you scroll down a bit, you can find it. It's the one that says "this input requires letters only"

Comment: That link seems dead.

Comment: Was trying to access it via the Dartium browser.   Good, got it, thank you.